# Can someone please explain my function deleteButton(this)?

Tags: javascript

Here is the link to my codepen to see all my code: http://codepen.io/stevengangano/full/LGvRdq/

My question has to do with my deleteButton function. I have trouble grasping this concept.

I created a function for the delete button called deleteButton(item).  I just want to know what does "item" and "parentNode" represent in the variable remove? Which one is the `<ul>` and which one is the `<li>`?

An explanation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please include the relevant code here as links may change.

Answer (score 2):

> `deleteButton(item)` is attached to the `removeButton`. `this` represents the current node which is button itself.

`item.parentNode` will be nothing but parent of the button which is `li` element. `remove` variable holds this `li` element.

Again `remove.parentNode` will return parent node of the `li` element which is `ul` element.

[`paretNode.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) *removes a child node from the DOM*

So in this case, **UL_ELEMENT.removeChild(LI_ELEMENT);**

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteButton(item) {
    var remove = item.parentNode;
    remove.parentNode.removeChild(remove);
}
```

in your code (posted offsite) is long for

```
function deleteButton(item) {
    item.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(item.parentNode); 
}
```

which removes the parent node of the clicked item from its grandparent node's list of children. The parent node of the delete button is `listItem` in code, which means an `LI` item will be deleted.

Elsewhere in code posted offsite (bad practice™) the delete function is defined as

```
removeButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteButton(this);');
```

which is *seriously really very,* interesting. It suggests that setting an onclick attribute with text, *after* HTML parsing has been completed, causes the text to be parsed as source for a javascript function which becomes the attribute value. Okay, so a setter can do this - but onEvent setters doing this is news to me. And testing indicates it being true.

So an answer is that setting the onclick attribute of a node  with text compiles the text to a function object, attaches the function object as the onclick attribute value, which when called by clicking supplies the node being clicked on as the `this` object for the onclick handler. If the function called removes the parent node of the clicked object, in this case an LI element gets removed.